# Can the edit summary be changed by users doing an additional edit from edit review?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits, edit-summary

I have observed a few times that, when I suggest an edit and that edit is accepted by someone else, but they add a further edit, then they seem to duplicate my edit summary in their own edit. However, this is usually not accurate to their edit.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55388652/revisions): revision 7 has the same edit summary as (my) revision 6.

Question (which is why I tagged this [support](/questions/tagged/support)): Is this just a default? Can the reviewer actually change the edit summary for their subsequent edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is the default *and* reviewers can change it. Both your actual edit (body/title/tags) *and* the edit summary are copied into the edit window when the reviewer chooses 'Improve and Edit' from the review queue. They'd have to *actively* change the edit summary, and since an edit summary is *optional* when you have full edit privileges, users (like me) often completely forget about it.